# Unable to to query Dictionary item using MongoDB C# 2.0 Drivers

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I have a class that has a dictionary property in it.

```
    [DataMember]
    [BsonElement("QueriableParameters")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> QueriableParameters
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

I'm using the new MongoDB c# 2.0 drivers and can't seem to be able to do this:

```
var selectQuery1 = await collection.Find(s => s.QueriableParameters["UniqueLoanNumber"] == "3049793b-91eb-49d8-a5b4-7cbfd1a1bb3c").ToListAsync();
```

I get this error stating that:

```
InnerException: System.InvalidOperationException
   HResult=-2146233079
   Message=s.QueriableParameters.get_Item("UniqueLoanNumber") is not supported.
   Source=MongoDB.Driver
   StackTrace:
        at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.GetSerializationInfo(Expression expression)
        at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.BuildComparisonQuery(Expression variableExpression, ExpressionType operatorType, ConstantExpression constantExpression)
```

Please help point me in the right direction.

Thanks,

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that with an expression. You probably need to use the query builders for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you Craig for the information.

I guess the only way to do it right now is to :

```
var builders = Builders<NotificationData>.Filter;
var filter = builders.Eq("QueriableParameters.UniqueLoanNumber", "theIdLookingfor");
var selectQuery = await collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible. This ticket has already been filed related to this: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-917.

Craig

Comment: That ticket was fixed but I ran into [a similar issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-2195).

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved in the latest Mongo C# driver version i.e 2.2.3.
Link: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver

Comment: I am still experiencing this in 2.7.2